# flux:wizard.link shows validation-error after update from typo3 7.6.4 to 7.6.11

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I use the `flux:wizard.link` in some content elements to create links to other internal pages:

```
        <flux:field.input name="url" label="Url">
            <flux:wizard.link activeTab="'page'" />
        </flux:field.input>
```

Since the Upgrade from Typo3 7.6.4 to 7.6.11 I see a validation-error in the backend when I open a content-element that uses this wizard:

[image]

It still renders the link right in the frontend, but I am not able to edit this content elements in the backend anymore.

What could it be?
How can I found out what causes this validation-error?

External URLs still works with the wizard and do not show any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you don`t use the current version of flux, since the issue has been fixed in flux 7.4.0 - see: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1116

Comment: thanks alot. And sorry for not checking this first myself.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You have to add target type of link after your page id,
In new version link works like

```
{page_id "target" "class/id" ...}
```